# How do I reduce the number of lines a calendar entry in Outlook 2013 uses. I only want one line per entry

Tags: windows-7, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2013

The Calendar in Outlook 2013 seems to use as much space as it can in Month View. When I enter a new Calendar item it might use one, two or even three lines when it has the space available. It includes a lot of information I don't need to see. This really clutters the look of my Calendar. I only really need the 'Subject' to show. I pretty much use Outlook Calendar exclusively in Month view, so this is quite annoying. Is there a way to reduce each Calendar item to only one line, ever?
I've looked through all the setting etc., but can't find the answer. 
I pretty sure this automatically happened in Outlook 2010 as I can't remember having to set this. 
I'm still using Windows 7, by the way. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I couldn't find any setting